# The general formula of the series: $22+21+20 + \cdots + 1 = 253$

Tags: summation, notation

Would the general formula of the series: $22+21+20 + \cdots +  1 = 253 $ expressed as a summation would be: $ X_i-\sum_{i=22}^n X_i-1 $? Or am I wrong?

I am sure this formula is basic but I could not find it.

This is a series from $22$ to $1$ but I try to figure out the general formula. If this formula have a standard name would be appreciate to know it. Thank you in advance.

Edit: Sorry I fixed the question

For example:

$$5+4+3+2+1 = 14$$
$$3+2+1 = 6$$

Would $ X_i-\sum_{i=22}^n X_i-1 $  be the general expression?

Comment: I don't understand your $-$ signs. This is clearly negative. In any case $253$ is the sum of all integers from $1$ to $22$.

Comment: As Bernard suggests: $$\sum_{i=1}^{22} i = 253$$

Comment: Are you trying to work out the notation/protocol for summing terms where the index is decreasing?

Comment: Thank you So general expression would be $ \sum_{i=1}^n i $ ?

Comment: Yeah @Mark Bennet. I mean, It's a sum but reversed . . I dont know if you understand me

Answer (score 2):

You could go with $$\sum_{n=1}^{22}(23-n)$$Note that each summand is positive, so the $-$ signs have to be kept under control. What you have written is definitely wrong.

Note that I have organised the index to count the number of terms ($22$), and then expressed the summands in terms of the index. Doing that will help you to keep things under control.

Comment: Thank you my friend. But this is particular case with 22. . How could I get the general formula for any number? Maybe like this : $ \sum_{i=1}^n n-i  $ where n is any constant ? or Am I wrong

Comment: @NIN You might need the term to be $n-i+1$ so that the first term is $n$ and the last term is $1$ (always check that the first and last terms are what you want them to be)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes called Gauß's sum, because of a story of him as a youth, we have that $1+2+3+\dots+n=\sum_{i=1}^ni=n(n+1)/2$.